# Getting "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I see this error message when I try to run almost any code
cant figure out why

```
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

for example when i run this simple code

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <omp.h> 

int main() { 

  printf ("Hello, world:"); 
  #pragma omp parallel 
    printf (" %d", omp_get_thread_num ()); 
  printf ("\n"); 
  return 0; 
}
```

tried other simple codes but nothing is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile your code with the flag `-fopenmp`. For example:

```
gcc -fopenmp -O3 -w -Wall -pedantic main.c
```

From [source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/Enabling-OpenMP.html) one can read:

> Enabling OpenMP
>
> **To activate the OpenMP extensions for C/C++ and Fortran, the
> compile-time flag -fopenmp must be specified.** This enables the OpenMP
> directive #pragma omp in C/C++ and !$omp directives in free form,
> c$omp, *$omp and !$omp directives in fixed form, !$ conditional
> compilation sentinels in free form and c$, *$ and !$ sentinels in
> fixed form, for Fortran. The flag also arranges for automatic linking
> of the OpenMP runtime library (Runtime Library Routines).